# Given a field $F$ and $R=F[x_1,...x_n]$, show the ideal $(x_1,x_2...x_i)$ is a prime ideal for each i

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Given a field $F$ and $R=F[x_1,...x_n]$, show the ideal $(x_1,x_2...x_i)$ is a prime ideal for each i

I think the simplest way of going about this would be to show that the quotient ring $R$ $mod (x_1,...x_i)$ is an integral domain. Is this a correct belief? Modding out by these $i$ generators would effectively reduce all terms of elements in R that contains an $x_i$ to zero, and thus reduce $R$ to $F[x_{i+1},...x_n]$, which is still an integral domain because... for some reason.. right?

Am I on the right track? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: If $R$ is an integral domain, then so is $R[x]$. Your approach is good.

Comment: My teacher is a real stickler for details... I want to define a sort of "projection" homomorphism from $F[x_1,....x_n]$ to $F[x_{i+1},....x_n]$ and then calculate the kernal as the ideal generated by the $x_i$ that are sent to zero, but am having trouble with the details. any suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelVaughan consider the map $\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx_k \mapsto \sum_{k=i+1} a_kx_k + a_0$

Comment: But that's not what polynomials in $F[x_1,...x_n]$ look like, each term in the polynomial can have any combination of the n different indeterminates to arbitrary powers, which is why i'm a bit overwhelmed.

Comment: When you write $x_2 \ldots x_n$, do you mean the product of the elements or the list of elements.  In the former case this is very untrue, although the ideal *is* semi-prime.  If you mean the latter, I would recommend enclosing the ellipsis in commas.

Comment: Also, if in the latter case, think about the homomorphism defined by evaluating  some of the $x_i$ at $0$ (this is equivalent to modding out by the $x_i$)